# MySQL Result offers duplicates, how to stop

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

With a MySQL Request i am receiving duplicates of the `id` and want to know if theres a way to prevent this.

Where

`drink:1` `food:2` `deli:3` `shelf:4`

Subnav 1 shows `11` twice.

example of the output
[image: example output]

Although the request returns accurately, i need the `id` to return only once. Is there a way to achieve this?

**The MySQL**

```
 <?
      $sql7x = " SELECT * FROM items_section_list ORDER BY item_sec_id ASC "; 
      $result7x = mysql_query($sql7x);
      while ($row7x = mysql_fetch_array($result7x)) { 

        $item_sec_id = $row7x['item_sec_id'];  
        $section_name = $row7x['section_name'];
    ?>
          <div id=''>
            subnav: <? echo $item_sec_id; ?> ::
            <?
            $sql8x = " SELECT * FROM item_groups 
                        WHERE section_id='$item_sec_id'
                        "; 
            $result8x = mysql_query($sql8x);

                while ($row8x = mysql_fetch_array($result8x)) { 

                    echo $item_sub_sec_id = $row8x['item_sub_sec_id'];  
                    echo ", ";
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT distinct(id) from...
```